# Python paint job estimator- Cant get functions to print

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried several different configurations and can not figure out why the final lines are not printing. Everything else seems to work as intended.
This program asks a user to enter the square feet of wall space to be painted and the price of the paint per gallon. The program should then display the following:

- number of gallons required
- hours of labor required
- cost of paint
- labor charges
- total cost(labor + paint)

  ```
   def main():
      squareFeet = float(input("Enter square feet of wall space to be painted:  "))
      pricePerGallon = float(input("Enter price of gallon of paint:  "))
      gallonsRequired = calcGallons
      hoursRequired = calcHours
      paintCost = calcPaintCost
      laborCost = calcLabor
      totalCost = calcTotal


  def calcGallons() :
      gallonsRequired = (squareFeet / 115) 
      return gallonsRequired

  def calcHours() :
      hoursRequired = (squareFeet / 115) * 8
      return hoursRequired


  def calcPaintCost() :
      paintCost = pricePerGallon * gallonsRequired
      return paintCost

  def calcLabor() :
      laborCost = hoursRequired * 40
      return laborCost

  def calcTotal() :
      totalCost = laborCost + paintCost
      return totalCost


      print(" Gallons of paint required:   ", gallonsRequired)
      print(" Hours of labor required:   ", hoursRequired)
      print("Cost of paint:   ", paintCost)
      print("Cost of labor:   ", laborCost)
      print("Total cost of paint job:   ", totalCost)


  main()
  ```

Comment: Can you format your code to a readable one ?

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of *scope*, *function calls*, and *return*.

#### Function Calls

In `main`, you are setting a bunch of variables like so:

```
gallonsRequired = calcGallons
```

What this is actually doing is setting the variable `gallonsRequired` to the *function* `calgGallons` **not** the result of that function.

What you *should* be doing is this:

```
gallonsRequired = calcGallons()
```

Do likewise for all of the other function calls.

#### Scope

Every function has its own scope. If you think of each function as a box, then its scope would be anything inside of it: variables, statements, etc. Any variable declared from within a function is in that function's scope. Thus, when you do this in `main`:

```
squareFeet = float(input("Enter square feet of wall space to be painted: "))
```

`squareFeet` is "stuck" inside. Other functions **cannot** access it. This is to allow for encapsulation of code. If you want other functions to have access to a variable, you must **pass** that variable into the function.

In this case, you need to access `squareFeet` from `calcGallons`. To do this, you need to pass `squareFeet` in when you call it like so:

```
gallonsRequired = calcGallons(squareFeet)
```

and you need to tell Python that you are expecting a parameter from your definition of `calcGallons` like so:

```
def calcGallons(squareFeet):
    return squareFeet / 115 # no need to set an extra variable
                            # just return the result of the statement
```

You need to do this for all of your function calls, but pass only the values that you need into each function. If you need more than one *parameter* (that's what you call the values you pass in), just comma separate them.

#### Returns

When you call `return` from within a function, that function exits *immediately* and (if you specify a return value) gives the result back to the caller. For example, in this scenario:

```
def foo():
    return 1
    print(5)

print(foo())
```

`1` will be printed to the console. Why? Because when `return 1` was called from within `foo`, `foo` exited and then the print function took the `1` that was returned and used it to print to the console.

---

**Other Notes**:

- According to the Pep8 Style Guide, use snake_case rather than camelCase for variable names